# Is there karate a way in karate dsl to implement an if /then else if/then for schema validation

Tags: json, if-statement, karate

I want to to be able to check two conditions if they are true i.e in karate
I have an array of data that I want to validate in the following way

> if "Documentation": "ID"
>      then "citizen": "YES" else
>    if "Documentation": "Passport"
>       then "citizen": "NO"

Here is the array data I want to validate

```
{
  "id": 7777,
  "name": "suzie",
  "surname": "Nedbank",
  "Documentation": "ID",
  "citizen": "YES",
},
```

tried approach:

```
* def Doc_type = function(x) { return x == "ID" || x == "Passport"}

* match response == 

{
"id": 7777,
"name": "suzie",
"surname": "Nedbank",
"Documentation": "#? Device_type(_)",
"citizen": "#($.Documentation == "ID" ? "citizen" : "YES" || $.Documentation == "Passport" ? "citizen" : "NO" )" 
}
```

error : 
 net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token | at position 154.

Comment: I made a mistake on "Documentation": "#? Device_type(_)", it was suppose to be "Documentation": "#? Doc_type(_)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, maybe it will give you a hint:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "id": 7777,
  "name": "suzie",
  "surname": "Nedbank",
  "Documentation": "ID",
  "citizen": "YES",
}
"""
* def isCitizen =
"""
function(x){ 
  var doc = $.Documentation;
  if (doc == 'ID') return x == 'YES';
  if (doc == 'Passport') return x == 'NO';
  return false;
}
"""
* match response ==
"""
{
  "id": 7777,
  "name": "suzie",
  "surname": "Nedbank",
  "Documentation": "#string",
  "citizen": "#? isCitizen(_)",
}
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for the response tried my best but i cannot see how you cater for : if "Documentation": "Passport" then "citizen": "NO" also

Comment: @SahFredFuze sorry I edited my answer. you can use `$` to do cross-field logic in JS

Comment: thank you the solution works but for some strange reason on an array it fails but on single return Item its good